# Is it possible to import gltf in python using file-like objects?

Tags: python, import, gltf, memory-management

I have encrypted and zipped gltf files on a server.
I need to import them in blender directly.
I found the way to load, decrypt and unzip the files to end-up with something like this :

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(decrypted_object)) as zip_ref:
for name in zip_ref.namelist() :
    print(name)
```

It prints the file name as an example, but may also write the file to disk if needed.

I would like to import the gltf content directly to the scene using something like this:

```
        import_path = (...)zip_ref(...) 
        bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath=import_path)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Edit: to be accurate, I want to use import_scene.gltf with the zip_ref from the code above. Or, to import the gltf content from a file like object and not from a file. I could not find a way in python to get a filepath to a file like object.

Comment: Yes, that appears to be correct: `bpy.ops.import_scene.gltf(filepath=import_path)`.  Did you try it?  Does it work?

Comment: No, it is not working. If I use import_path, the filepath is the file content and not the file path. I am asking for the right way to do it, if even possible.

Comment: No, you can't do it. You'll have to extract the ZIP and pass a path to import_scene.gltf.